# Kata: What's up next? - How to access function generator in Tests?

Tags: javascript, function, generator

The problem I have is the last test (the function generator) is always failing.

I want to learn how to manipulate the function generator from the tests section, because when I try accessing the generator function from the main code section, I fail.

I tried to access it many different ways but always get `empty object`, `undefined` or `countFrom() is not defined`.

From the documentation, I read that I have to use `.next()` to access, and compare, the values.

My code:

```
function nextItem(xs, item) {

  let count = 1;

  for(let el of xs) {

    if(el === item) {

      return xs[count];

    }
    count++;    

  }
}
```

Tests:

```
Test.assertEquals(nextItem([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8], 5), 6);
Test.assertEquals(nextItem(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'd'), undefined);
Test.assertEquals(nextItem(['a', 'b', 'c'], 'c'), undefined);
Test.assertEquals(nextItem("testing", "t"), "e");
function* countFrom(n) { for (let i = n; ; ++i){ yield i;} }
Test.assertEquals(nextItem(countFrom(1), 12), 13);
```

Comment: Can you elaborate, what you want to know? If you need a list of solutions, you can just click the forfeit challenge button and see a ton, so that can't be it? If you want to know how iterators work, there is [Iterators and Generators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Iterators_and_Generators).

Comment: What I want to learn is `how to manipulate the function generator from the tests section?` as when I try accessing it from the main code section I fail.@ASDFGerte

It seems that the solution code block and the tests code block in codewars are not connected and I really don't know how to itterate a function written down in the tests section from the solution section.